# How to find out the dimensions of clipboard screenshot image from paste event

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there's a way for knowing the width and height of a clipboard screenshot without having to render it using `img` tag in the DOM.

I am trying to resize the screenshot image so it can fit 600px container without having to show the vertical and horizontal scrollbar.
[image]

Comment: Do you have to render the image/screenshot, no. But you will need to load it in order to get the dimensions as that information is not stored in the clipboard information. Though I wonder why CSS can't just be used to fit the image to the container?

Comment: I want to maintain the screenshot image ratio

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. With CSS you can maintain the aspect ratio and force it to fit within a container fairly easily by setting the `max-width` and `max-height` values to `100%`. Here is an example on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/EssXTee/pen/XWYdROB) that does just this with 2 different aspect ratios and images. Both images are larger than the 600x600px container for at least 1 dimension but the aspect ratio is preserved.

Comment: Thanks, a lot this can solve my problem :)